# jsdoc тип данных

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Как в jsdoc указать, что функция возвращает тот же тип данных, что был ей передан?

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} data 
 * @returns {???} 
 */
function random(data) {
    // ...
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Generic Types](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types)

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} data 
 * @returns {T} 
 */
function random(data) {
  // ...
  return data;
}
```